Comedy movie where protagonist is late to a special event, and is having a lot of travel trouble
Comedy movie from the 80s or 90s. 
The protagonist is on a time-pressured journey to a special event (wedding?), and is having a lot of travel trouble. After missing a key transport, an old man in a Cadillac offers to help, saying he can drive him there in 4 (2? 3?) hours. Incredulous, but optimistic, the protagonist takes the ride. 
When they start on their journey, however, it quickly becomes clear to the protagonist that he will NOT get to his destination in 4 hours, for they are traveling at a terribly slow speed. As they roll through some farmland, a farmer (shepherd?) passes the car, walking faster than it. The protagonist says "Are you sure we're going to get there in time? Can I drive? Do you mind going a little faster? I thought you said it would take 4 hours!" To the last one, the old driver mildly replies "Well it FEELS like 4 hours! Look at all the beautiful scenery around us." 
I am imagining the star to be Steve Martin, Martin Short, John Cleese, Chevy Chase, or anyway someone of that type. But after scouring their IMDB pages, I'm not so sure. 

Pretty sure this is the sequel to The Odd Couple, The Odd Couple II from 1998, where Walter Mattahu and Jack Lemmon go through all kinds of trouble when they try to reach their childrens' wedding in time. Along the way, an old man offers them a ride, saying that though it's a five hour drive, they will be there "in less than two hours". But when they actually set off, the old man is driving very slowly, and as they drive by a rural landscape, they're passed by a group of joggers and then a bunch of hikers on foot. They confront him about it and this exchange takes place:

LEMMON: No offence, but do you really think we can make San Malina in two hours?
OLD MAN: Who said that?
LEMMON: You did, last night.
OLD MAN: No, no, no. I think you misunderstood me. What I meant was I can make this five hour trip seem like two hours. Take in the scenery! Relax! Enjoy being alive and well.

Ironically, the old man then drops dead behind the wheel. The car, however, is an expensive Rolls Royce. Here's a clip that happens right after the old man dies:




Sounds like Planes, Trains and Automobiles starring Steve Martin, where he's an executive trying to get home for Christmas?

While this is one of the first things that comes to mind when thinking about 80s movies about a man getting into an oddyssey while being late, it doesn't seem to match many of the details in the question, or you might want to further explain in which way it does.

Thanks for the guess, but that's not the movie.

Alternately if it's John Cleese, it could be Clockwise.  He's a time obsessed head teacher who has disasters trying to make an important meeting.

This was my first thought too, and even if it's wrong it's a great movie.

Excellent guess, but I rewatched that recently and didn't find the scene in there.
